# large monitor off center display

Tags: display

I use a Sharp 42" TV as my only monitor and sometimes the display is off to the left so I can't see the launcher. However, if I move the cursor to the left, I see the tail of some of the longer bubbles so I can tell which button I'm on and be able to click it to launch the app.

Interestingly, at times the display corrects itself and the launch ribbon shows up on the screen.
I need to know why this happens.

I ran the command `xrandr` in the terminal and [the output is here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10635295).

There are no centering or size controls on the TV and when I tried to set it up, the display said it was a 29" monitor...

Today I turned it on and booted about 8 times and could not get the display . I then hooked up a 15" monitor, which it detected and all is normal, but I would like to go back to the large screen.

EDIT
I have a Sharp LC42SB45U TV

I pasted in `~/.config/monitors.xml` and got this -

```
bash: /home/rogrrr/.config/monitors.xml: Permission denied
```

EDIT March 22 - Computer still boots with off center display but when I start it with a standard monitor it is normal. Then I change the cable to the large display and that is normal too.
I still cannot figure out why this is.
Any thoughts ?

Comment: We aren't asking you to understand it - just copy and paste it. Try running these commands first: `sudo apt-get install pastebinit` and enter your password and press enter to install. Then run the command `xrandr | pastebinit` and give us the link. That means you don't need to paste a lot of text. @Fabby will understand what the output means, don't worry about what it says.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post new info, so that all the information is gathered in one place.  Also delete all your comments as this is starting to look like a chat room.  ;-) What is the model number of your TV and can you also post the output of your `~/.config/monitors.xml`